# What is higher dimension solid torus?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

For solid torus, I mean a connected component of the complement of 'some embedding' of $T^{n-1}$ inside $S^n$. Is there any `canonical' one?
Is it just $D^2\times\cdots \times S^1$? But it seems there are many position of putting $D^2$ in the product. But we should have only 2 complement!?

But at dimension $n=3$, this is not an issue, since there are exact 2 places to put it, corresponding to two solid torus in $S^3$.

Comment: You mean a connected component of the complement?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, edited.thx

Comment: Yes, and that's the picture of writing $S^3$ as the union of two solid tori, intersecting along a torus.